# How does -newObject get called in Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm doing *Cocoa Programming: For Mac OS X 4th Edition*, I'm at Chap 11. "Basic Core Data" and I can not figure out how `-(id)newObject` gets called.

We do link `add:` to the `carArrayController` but that is it. 
If I add `-(void)add:(id)sender` to `carArrayController` then `-(id)newObject` does not get called. 
This tell me there is some sort of hierarchy calling system but I cant find information on the subject. How does it get called?

`-(id)newObject` is from NSObjectController.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking that's not in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSObjectController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002044-BBCEAICF) for this method.

Answer (score 0):

The CarArrayController is a subclass of NSArrayController. In the CarArrayController subclass when you override `-add:sender` you must be sure to have  `[super add:sender];` in your method since it is in the NSArrayController method of `-add:sender` that `-newObject` is called. You will often need to invoke the `super` implementation of a method when you override a method in a subclass.

Comment: How does Button Add that is linked to add: know it had to call -newObject? Nowhere did I explicitly link them or call it. Then if I add -(void)add:(id)sender how did button Add linked to add: know it  had to call -(void)add:(id)sender and not -(id)newObject.

Comment: You overrode `-add:sender` and decided that `-newObject` doesn't get called. It does get called if you override it properly by calling `[super add:sender];`. When you don't override `add:sender` it already gets called by way of the `super`. When NSArrayController (`super`) invokes `-add:sender` that method, the one in NSArrayController, is where `-newObject` gets called. NSArrayController is a subclass of NSObjectController, so it likely calls `[super newObject];` early in its implementation.

Comment: I was going to change my comment since I figured it out but you answered. I tried to find documentation related to this and found nothing. Does documentation for this exist or is it a case of trial by error? Is it explicitly written in the docs that add: will call newObject if present or a list of what it looks for?

Comment: The documentation for NSObjectController tells about `-newObject` and how it works when adding and inserting objects. And I see your point that you have to know about `-newObject` before you can learn about it. Sort of like trying to look up how to spell 'pneumonia.'

Comment: Thank's Mike. 
So, to figure it out you have to figure out, how Apple decided to build the documents & understanding the programming lingo but mostly the logic behind the documents structure! Even then it's not explicitly written. SO...
Cars inherits from NSArrayController. 
NSArrayController has `add:` (empty documentation) 
NSArrayController inherits from NSObjectController and also has `add:`. In it's documentation it mentions **see -newObject**. This is the only location in the document that kind of links `-add:` to `-newObject`.
Am I correct?

Comment: The books help a lot, too. The one you have is very good. General principals include being sure to look into the superclasses and always consider calling  `super` when overriding.